# Сменить пользователя Git

Tags: git, github

Пол года назад установил себе на домашний пк с windows 7 git. Зарегистрировал аккаут залил пару репозиториев но в целом почти не пользовался. Во время первой настройки указал имя пользователя и почту.

> git config --global user.name1
>
> git config --global user.email1

Спустя время уже с другого компьютера зарегистрировал новую учетку, и при первом запуске git в консоли прописал уже name2 и user.email2. Теперь возникла ситуация что на рабочем пк в Git стоит user.name2 а на домашнем user.name1 из за этого при попытке залить репозиторий возникает ошибка 403. Логин и пароль не спрашивает только выдает ошибку. Вопрос : как выйти или вообще удалить своего старого user.name1 и зайти в гит под новой учеткой?

ввожу git remote -v
получаю
fatal: Not a git repository (or any of the parent directories): .git

Comment: добавьте в вопрос результат `git remote -v`

Comment: в том вопросе нет ответа который мне бы помог. я удалил учетку гита из --Панель управления\Учетные записи пользователей и семейная безопасность\Диспетчер учетных данных-- но при новом запуске все еще захожу в user.name1

Comment: стоит заметить, что имя системного пользователя в Windows, имя github пользователя и имя, используемое git для выбранного репозитория, могут отличаться друг от друга. `git remote -v` следует выполнять в директории с git репозиторием.

Comment: как мне сменить имя github пользователя и имя, используемое git для выбранного репозитория ?

Comment: @Сергей, git config --global - настройки по умолчанию для всех репозиториев, git config --local - для конкретного (выполнять в папке рабочей копии). Подробнее в справке по git config

Comment: git config --global устанавливаются при первом запуске? их можно сменить ?

Comment: @Сергей конфиги можно менять в любой момент, и сами они не устанавливаются, только вашими руками.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Опции в `git config` не имеют отношения к доступу на гитхаб*.** Они используются только в данных о коммитах. Обычно используется только адрес электронной почты для установления, кем совершён коммит. Если по email-адресу аккаунт на гитхабе не распознан, показывается просто имя.

При доступе к репозиторию (push, pull, fetch, clone) по HTTPS при всех действиях с участием сервера вас попросят ввести логин и пароль на гитхабе. В зависимости от ОС, настроек и дистрибутива Git они могут сохраняться в [хранилище учётных данных](https://git-scm.com/book/ru/v2/%D0%98%D0%BD%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D1%83%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D1%8B-Git-%D0%A5%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%89%D0%B5-%D1%83%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%85-%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%85) ([под Windows, например, таком](https://github.com/Microsoft/Git-Credential-Manager-for-Windows), его записи можно найти и удалить [в дебрях панели управления](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15382950/2076787)).

А при доступе к репозиторию по SSH гитхаб узнаёт аккаунт **по SSH-ключу**. Узнать, какими ключами пытается воспользоваться Git, можно в **Git Bash** (который во всех известных мне дистрибутивах Git для Windows *есть*) следующей командой:

```
ssh -v git@github.com 2>&1 | grep "Trying private key"
```

> Спросить у гитхаба о доступе к SSH, сваливая все результаты в стандартный вывод (`2>&1`), достать из результатов строчки, содержащие `"Trying private key"`

---

* Обычно. В настройках [может быть задана особая SSH-команда с реквизитами](https://superuser.com/a/912281/379403) (в вашем случае вряд ли) или настройки хранилища учётных данных (а вот это может быть, но реквизитами в этом случае заведует хранилище, не конфиг).

Comment: Так что мне сделать что бы залить новый комит или проект на гитхаб?

Comment: @Сергей грохнуть сохранённый аккаунт гитхаба (если он где-то сохранён) следуя указаниям в ответе. Либо это будет запись в хранилище учётных данных, либо файл SSH-ключа (в ответе приведена команда, которая поможет его найти). А затем настроить доступ по новой.

Comment: 45 простите, но я создал акк на гитхабе и скачал сам гит - на одном компе и мне просто нужно залить(со скачиванием проблем не было) изменения в ту же ветку, в тот же аккаут с другого компа. неужели это настолько сложно, или я реально ничего не понимаю?(

Comment: Отличный ответ, не знал про тестирование ssh-доступа подобным образом.