# при работе с GitLab по протоклу Git всегда получаю ошибку "Permission denied, please try again." По HTTPS - все работает!

Tags: git, svn, gitlab, git-svn

GitLab самой последней версии (9.2.5) установлен на виртуальной машине с Ubuntu 16.04 в локальной сети. Первоначальную настройку я сделал по руководству с сайта GitLab и потом получил Let's encrypt'овский сертификат, по [руководству:](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-secure-gitlab-with-let-s-encrypt-on-ubuntu-16-04)
Наружу прокинуты порты 443 и 22, прописана a-запись в публичном домене, и сайт https://gitlab0.junecat.ru номально открывается.
Более того, я завёл пользователей, проекты, и начал работать, правда, при любой операции приходится в качестве протокла выбирать https.

- как починить работу с протоколом git?

Вот демонстрация проблемы с этим протоколом, я взял "чистенькую" машину с Win 7, поставил на неё putty и Git for windows.

Потом я проверил во первых - что я могу соединяться по putty с 22-м портом хоста gitlab0.junecat.ru.
Потом я настроил глобальные параметры git - конфига user.name и user.email

Потом я попробовал склонировать репозиторий на эту новую Win7 - машину, вот скриншот и все сообщения в виде текста:

> C:>mkdir GitProjects
>
> C:>cd GitProjects
>
> C:\GitProjects>git clone
>   git@GitLab0.junecat.ru:konst/TradingG0_Solution.git
>
> Cloning into 'TradingG0_Solution'...
>
> The authenticity of host 'gitlab0.junecat.ru (77.246.237.76)' can't be
>   established.
>
> ECDSA key fingerprint is
>   SHA256:8dMOgDXYjZWRj+bqEacWKTt00uppdB1A2cL/0GL4Ua8.
>
> Are you sure you want to continue connecting (yes/no)? yes
>
> Warning: Permanently added 'gitlab0.junecat.ru,77.246.237.76' (ECDSA)
>   to the list of known hosts.
>
> git@gitlab0.junecat.ru's password:
>
> Permission denied, please try again.
>
> git@gitlab0.junecat.ru's password:

Обратите внимание на следующие моменты:

1) ссылка, которую я использую для клонирования, взята из моего GitLab'а.
Вот эти ссылки для обеих протоклов:

git: git@GitLab0.junecat.ru:konst/TradingG0_Solution.git

https: https://tst@GitLab0.junecat.ru/konst/TradingG0_Solution.git

При клонировании не спрашивался пользователь, только пароль. причем ссылка начинается с git@ - это вообще правильно? такого пользователя, если что, нет в системе. Имя пользователя, от имени когторго я работаю - tst, это хорошо видно в https - ссылке.

Вы можете спросить "зачем тебе вообще git, работай через https". Но при работе по https при push'е всегда запрашивается пароль. А мне надо импортировать большие проекты из SVN, и для автоматизации я хотел бы написать скрипты, которым разрешу push'ить без пароля.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: нигде не вижу, что бы Вы писали о том, что сгенерировали приватный ключ и добавили его в гитлаб.

Comment: Я действительно добавил приватный ключ в гитлаб.
Точнее, я сгенерировал ключ и добавил в гитал его публичную часть.
Но это пролисходило не на тестовой машине, на которой я демонстрировал проблему!
Именно поэтому - вопрос: я вообще не понимаю механику работы этих ключей. Я его добавил потому, что GitLab орал "добавь ключ, добавь ключ". Как этот ключ связан с машиной, на которой происходит доступ по SSH?

Comment: тогда делайте проверку с своей локальной машины
`ssh -T git@gitlab0.junecat.ru`. Должно нормально отработать. (да, лучше использовать git-bash, а не git-cmd)

Comment: Нет, с локальной машины - не работает. 
GitBash - сейчас на тестовой машине на него переключусь и на тестовой машине сделаю новую пару (public - private) ключей

Comment: На локальной машине картина такая:
C:\Users\davydov>ssh -T git@gitlab0.junecat.ru
The authenticity of host 'gitlab0.junecat.ru (192.168.10.57)' can't be established.
RSA key fingerprint is de:4d:e5:9b:dc:40:0f:a1:de:e9:65:fd:1b:8f:89:54.
Are you sure you want to continue connecting (yes/no)? yes
Warning: Permanently added 'gitlab0.junecat.ru,192.168.10.57' (RSA) to the list of known hosts.
git@gitlab0.junecat.ru's password:
Permission denied, please try again.
git@gitlab0.junecat.ru's password:
Permission denied, please try again.
git@gitlab0.junecat.ru's password:

Comment: Связанный вопрос: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/651630/181100

Comment: Большое спасибо!
Ваша подсказка насчет того, как добавить SSH-ключ именно для той машины, с которой будет происходить доступ по SSH - помогла.
Я добавил в path путь к файлу ssh.exe (иначе под виндой команда ssh не работала), потом я сгенерировал ключ, и потом МАГИЧЕСКИ та же самая команда сработала, причём без всякого запроса пароля.
Сейчас добьавлю картинку к своему вопросу.

Comment: я думал, что это слишком очевидно, что на машине должна быть приватная часть ключа (она может генерироваться на другой машине). Иначе можно было бы легко получить доступ к любому репозиторию в мире.

Comment: "я думал, что это слишком очевидно, что на машине должна быть приватная часть ключа" - вы правы. Некоторая сложность возникает, когда используешь Git из командной строки и никогда не видел, как он работает. (При правильно сгененрированной паре ключей - он просто не спрашивает пароль. А при отстутствии клбючей или неправильно сгенерированной паре - он спрашивает его снова и снова, и ни один пароль не подходит.)

Answer (score 1):

> я вообще не понимаю механику работы этих ключей

упрощённо и без упоминания (для простоты) нескольких важных этапов:

1. клиент генерирует пару ключей: открытый и закрытый. связаны они тем, что зашифрованное с помощью **данного** открытого ключа можно расшифровать лишь с помощью **данного** закрытого ключа (и наоборот — зашифрованное данным закрытым ключом можно расшифровать лишь с помощью данного открытого ключа).
2. при соединении с ssh-сервером ssh-клиент предъявляет свой открытый ключ.
3. сервер убеждается, что полученный им открытый ключ присутствует среди тех, которым доступ разрешён, шифрует этим открытым ключом некоторую случайную последовательность байт и отсылает её назад клиенту.
4. клиент расшифровывает присланное (это можно сделать лишь с помощью имеющегося у него секретного ключа) и отсылает обратно.
5. сервер сличает присланное с исходной случайной последовательностью, и, таким образом убеждается, что клиент **действительно** обладает **данным** секретным ключом.

Comment: Спасибо! И небольшое дополнение, которое я как раз упустил: как правило "клиент" - это "клиентский компьютер", и для каждого клиентского компьютера процедуру генерации пары ключей (и добавления публичной части ключа в гитлаб) надо выполнять отдельно.

Comment: это не обязательное условие. ключ (обе части) можно и скопировать с одного клиента на другой. с точки зрения «суровой безопасности» это, вероятно, плохо, но с технической точки зрения — более чем работоспособно.

Comment: Вообще говоря, да.
Скорее, важно понимать, что они должны присутствовать на компе. И для новичка самый простой способ - просто их сгененрировать.

Answer (score 0):

Господа, 
пользователь KoVadim дал мне очень ценную подсказку.
Он написал "я нигде не видел, что Вы генерировали и добавляли SSH-ключи в GitLab".

Это правда.

Сейчас - как пелена с глаз спала.

Меня ввело в заблуждение то, что вообще то я это делал, но не для той машины, на котрой проводил тесты.

То есть, когда человек хочет работать со своего компьютера MyComp с гитлабом по протоколу SSH, он должен именно на этом компе MyComp выполнить процедуру генерации ключей, как [описано](https://git-scm.com/book/ru/v1/Git-%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D1%81%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5-%D0%A1%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BA%D1%80%D1%8B%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE-SSH-%D0%BA%D0%BB%D1%8E%D1%87%D0%B0), в моём случае - еще и поправить PATH чтобы команда ssh работала из командной строки.

Затем нужно пойти в свой профиль на GitLab и добавить туда публичную часть ключа.

А после этого - никакой пароль уже не будет нужен, команда git clone будет работать сразу. Смотрите картинку, как я сгенерировал ключ и как изменилось поведение после добавления ключа:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Спасибо!