# Удостоверьтесь, что у вас есть необходимые права доступа и репозиторий существует

Tags: git, pycharm, gitlab

Пытаюсь клонировать gitlab репозиторий с помощью ssh, но при попытке сделать через терминал выдает следующее:

```
git@gitlab.com: Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: Не удалось прочитать из внешнего репозитория.

Удостоверьтесь, что у вас есть необходимые права доступа
и репозиторий существует.
```

В терминале пишу следующее:

```
git clone git@gitlab.com:(название репозитория).git
```

Не могу понять в чем проблема, помогите пожалуйста

Comment: Что говорит `ssh git@gitlab.com` ?

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [при работе с GitLab по протоклу Git всегда получаю ошибку "Permission denied, please try again." По HTTPS - все работает!](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/679220/%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b8-%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b1%d0%be%d1%82%d0%b5-%d1%81-gitlab-%d0%bf%d0%be-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d1%82%d0%be%d0%ba%d0%bb%d1%83-git-%d0%b2%d1%81%d0%b5%d0%b3%d0%b4%d0%b0-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bb%d1%83%d1%87%d0%b0%d1%8e-%d0%be%d1%88%d0%b8%d0%b1%d0%ba%d1%83-permission-denied-pl)